# Is cassandra suitable for analytics storing?

Tags: cassandra

I'm willing to develop an open-source analytics project which will store visits, referers, devices (by kind, family etc.).

I'm fairly new to the cassandra world so I'm asking a lot of questions about modeling with it.

I have read a [lot](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/) of [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_intro_c.html) about it, here is a part of my datamodel:

```
create table visits(
    id                      UUID,
    remote_addr             VARCHAR,
    method                  VARCHAR,
    user_agent              VARCHAR,
    status_code             INT,
    host                    VARCHAR,
    protocol                VARCHAR,
    path                    VARCHAR,
    data                    VARCHAR,
    headers                 VARCHAR,
    query_string            VARCHAR,
    referer_id              UUID,
    device_id               UUID,
    browser_id              UUID,
    platform_id             UUID,
    created_at              TIMEUUID,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC);

create table referers(
    id                      UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    host                    VARCHAR,
    path                    VARCHAR,
    first_seen              TIMESTAMP,
    last_seen               TIMESTAMP,
    seen_count              INT );

create table browsers(
    id                      UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    key                     VARCHAR,
    version                 VARCHAR,
    first_seen              TIMESTAMP,
    last_seen               TIMESTAMP,
    seen_count              INT );

create table platforms(
    id                      UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    key                     VARCHAR,
    version                 VARCHAR,
    first_seen              TIMESTAMP,
    last_seen               TIMESTAMP,
    seen_count              INT );
```

With this model, if I want for example "all visits from status_code 200" I will have to create a secondary index, same for referers, devices, etc.

So do I need to create individual tables "visits_by_referers", "visits_by_devices" like so:

```
create table visits_by_referers(
    visit_id                UUID,
    device_id               UUID,
    PRIMARY KEY (visit_id, device_id)
);
```

or am I completely wrong and cassandra is not suitable for this?

Thank you :)

Comment: My learnings from cassandra are: know what queries you want to ask and model the data storage for this purpose. So it won't be very flexible. My learnings on analytics are: over the time will arise different questions that (probably) will not fit very well to the data model and flexibility is very welcome. At least I would think twice using it. But I'm interested in other opinions :)

Answer (score 1):

Until 3.0 comes out with Materialized Views (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6477), which will be HUGE for this type of use case, you need to create individual tables for things like 'visits by referrer' if you plan on doing direct querying.

What a lot of people tend to do is use a single large table, and then overlay something like Spark to actually read the data into memory and do much more complicated querying.